# Kendo drop down list doesn't work in IE10 iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, frames, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My mvc website makes use of the Telerik Kendo mvc dll's. However the problem is that the drop down list doens't work when running it on IE10, in a website that uses frames. When I run it on its own, it works fine, however as soon as it is used on a website with frames, it brakes the drop down list and they won't expand.

I'm currently using the latest version (2012.913) of the Kendo UI for MVC.

Is there a solution for this.?

Comment: can you show the code snippent

Comment: sometimes updating the JQuery library helps

Comment: Had the same problem where our kendo based app is in an iframe, and a lot of the kendo controls didn't respond. The reason was that the iframe was stealing focus from the kendo controls within.

Comment: @gitsitgo How did you many to fix the issue?

Comment: Basically, our solution was to not use an iframe, which was a valid option for us... but I know it's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: You are correct, that is not going to be a valid option for us :(

Comment: Btw, I'm almost certain that's not the latest version. Try a newer one, perhaps it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I'd share since we had the same issue and found the fix for it.  Unfortunately we are forced to continue using frames as well, so we had to put this fix in place.
First thing to check is if your using compatibility mode in the browser, whether by the site being added to the compatibility list or you're on an intranet site.  If you can, disable compatibility mode and that should resolve this.  If you want to ensure your site isn't using compatibility mode, add this tag to your application.

The problem we had is that IE doesn't obey this setting when using frames...it will always use whatever the parent frame is set to.  We had to have compatibility mode enabled for certain portions of our site, so we were in a catch-22 situation.  Since there's no way around this, our final resolution was to re-direct the user behind the scenes if they navigated to the page in the iFrame.
That being said, the easiest option is to add the meta tag above if you don't need compatibility view for anything.